# How to obtain a receipt for Indian Visa payment?

Tags: visas, india, payment

My colleague applied for, and was granted, an Indian visa at the end of 2018. Our employer now requires a receipt for the payment and my colleague is stating that they do not have one.

Does anyone know how to obtain a receipt for the payment after the visa has been granted?

Comment: To whom was the payment made?

Comment: The payment was made to Ministry of Home Affairs. I've emailed their visa support but all I got back was to login and print off receipt. I've spoken to my colleague and they've said that there is nowhere to login into. Any ideas?

Comment: @Marianne How did they pay? Assuming the visa cost wasn’t enormous, will your employer accept a copy of the credit card statement and the visa itself as evidence? Your question reads as if the visa was work-related, if so what’s the expenses policy on dealing with missing/unavailable receipts?

Comment: Yes it is work related and paid for using a work credit card. However the amount taken in is US$ so need some form of receipt apparently

Comment: I always (successfully) use a photo of the credit card bill. Before you jump through hoops, make sure it is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Have your colleague check his email back to when he did his visa. Find the email from the visa application website that they sent to show that the application was submitted. Right after there should be a receipt provided this person paid immediately upon submission. Furthermore, for what it's worth, if your a US citizen the visas come out to exactly 103.50 US dollars.